# How to import geojson files in postgresql database?

Tags: python, postgresql, geojson

I download WFS (Web Features Services) geojson files into my workspace with this script and it's working and now I want to insert them into a new postgres database but I don't know how to do it... I read several tutorials but I can't manage it and most of the times it's with json files (but I think that a St_Geomfromtext can fix it ?)

Here is my script to download WFS geojson files into my workspace

```
import requests

def download (url,d):
   response = requests.get(url)
   if response.ok :
      with open("D:/test_wfs/"+d+".geojson", 'wb') as f:
         f.write(response.content)

def main():
   url = "mywfsurl"
   conn = psycopg2.connect(
      user="XXX",
      password="XXX",
      database="data_base",
      host="XXX",
      port="5432",
      )
   print("Successfully connected!")
   cur = conn.cursor()
   sql ="select id from public.base"
   cur.execute(sql)

   row = [item[0] for item in cur.fetchall()]

   for d in row:
      download(url+"'"+d+"'",d)
      
   print("Download completed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```